# Как обновить JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

В первой колонке располагаются кнопки и если кликнуть по любой а затем добавить
строки, то остается белая строка при добавлении строк. Как нормально обновить таблицу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package main;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TableTest {

private JFrame frame;
private JTable table;
private TableModel model;
private int count = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TableTest window = new TableTest();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public TableTest() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Example");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    model = new TableModel();
    model.addRow(createRow());
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new RowRender());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
//  table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton btnClear = new JButton("CLEAR");
    btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            getModel().clearHistory();
        }
    });

    JButton btnCreateRow = new JButton("CREATE ROW");
    btnCreateRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            getModel().addRow(createRow());
        }
    });
    panel.add(btnCreateRow);
    panel.add(btnClear);
}

class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] column = { "One", "Two" };

    private LinkedList<ArrayList<Object>> rows;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    TableModel() {
        this.rows = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
            if (i == columnIndex) {
                return column[i];
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return column.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return rows.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex);
    }

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
    }

    void addRow(ArrayList<Object> row) {
        rows.addFirst(row);
        while (rows.size() >= 11) {
            rows.removeLast();
        }
        fireTableRowsInserted(0, getRowCount());
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void clearHistory() {
        rows.clear();
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

}

public TableModel getModel() {
    return model;
}

public ArrayList<Object> createRow() {
    ArrayList<Object> row = new ArrayList<Object>();
    JButton button = new JButton(count + " Click me");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Pressed");
        }
    });
    row.add(button);
    row.add("Text");
    count++;
    return row;
}

class ButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton jButton;

    public ButtonEditor() {
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row,
            int column) {
        jButton = (JButton) value;
        return (JButton) value;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return jButton;
    }

    public JButton getjButton() {
        return jButton;
    }

    public void setjButton(JButton jButton) {
        this.jButton = jButton;
    }
}

public class ButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
        return (Component) value;
    }
}

public class RowRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {

        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        return cell;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: У меня ваш код нажатию на `Clear` все строки стирает. Либо объясните нормально, как достить ошибку.

Comment: @Denis он уже написал в комментарии к другому ответу сначала нажимаем кнопку "Click me", потом на "Create Row". Сам не могу понять где ошибка,такое ощущение, что render вступает в конфликт с editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сообщать таблице, что редактирование завершено. Иначе таблица считает, что ячейка еще редактируется, и не перерисовывает ее. Для этого есть метод `AbstractCellEditor.stopCellEditing`. Можно дополнить ваш `ButtonEditor.getTableCellEditorComponent` еще одним слушателем нажатия на кнопку:

```
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    jButton = (JButton) value;
    jButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ButtonEditor.this.stopCellEditing();
            jButton.removeActionListener( this );
        }
    });
    return (JButton) value;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что используется анонимный класс, а не лямбда, т.к. для удаления слушателя нужена ссылка на него (`this`). Можно еще сделать `ButtonEditor` реализацией `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
tableModel.fireTableDataChanged()
```

Comment: одинаково, что тот - что этот вариант - кнопка не стирается.